# Streamlit Bokeh Event Callback to get Clicked values

Tags: callback, bokeh, streamlit

I am trying to get values from the click when the user clicks on dot in scatter plot.
the below shows the plot but no values are shown for the dictionary at the end.

Since it's streamlit, it uses bokeh==2.4.3

```
import streamlit as st
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS

# Create a Streamlit web app
st.title("Interactive Scatter Plot")

# Create some example data
data = {
    "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "y": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
}

# Create a Bokeh figure and add a scatter plot
p = figure(title="Click on a dot", tools="tap,reset")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
scatter = p.circle("x", "y", size=20, source=source)

# Create a JavaScript callback function
callback_code = """
    const selected_indices = cb_obj.indices;
    if (selected_indices.length > 0) {
        const selected_index = selected_indices[0];
        const x_value = source.data['x'][selected_index];
        const y_value = source.data['y'][selected_index];
        
        clicked_data.x = x_value;
        clicked_data.y = y_value;
    }
"""
clicked_data = {"x": None, "y": None}
callback = CustomJS(
    args={"source": source, "clicked_data": clicked_data}, code=callback_code
)

# Attach the JavaScript callback to the scatter plot
scatter.js_on_event("tap", callback)


# Display the Bokeh plot in Streamlit
st.bokeh_chart(p, use_container_width=True)

st.write(clicked_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to get a value from front-end to backend, for that you need a webhook or websocket. It has nothing to do with Bokeh/streamlit.

In case, you just require to update some component within the UI, create all the component in Bokeh, change it in your callback, and send entire UI to streamlit.

In the code below, I am updating `x, y` basis the point selected -

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Div
from bokeh.layouts import Column

# Create a Streamlit web app
st.title("Interactive Scatter Plot")

# Create some example data
data = {
    "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "y": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
}

clicked_data = {"x": None, "y": None}

# Create a Bokeh figure and add a scatter plot
p = figure(title="Click on a dot", tools="tap,reset")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
scatter = p.circle("x", "y", size=20, source=source)
div = Div(text  = str(clicked_data))

c = Column(p, div)


# Create a JavaScript callback function
callback_code = """
    const selected_indices = cb_obj.indices;
    if (selected_indices.length > 0) {
        const selected_index = selected_indices[0];
        const x_value = source.data['x'][selected_index];
        const y_value = source.data['y'][selected_index];
        
        clicked_data.x = x_value;
        clicked_data.y = y_value;
        div.text = '{"x" : ' + x_value + ',  "y" : ' + y_value +'}';
    }
    else{
        div.text = '{"x" : ' + 'None' + ',  "y" : ' + 'None' +'}';
    }
 
    div.change.emit();
"""
callback = CustomJS(
    args={"source": source, "clicked_data": clicked_data, "div" : div}, code=callback_code
)

# Attach the JavaScript callback to the scatter plot
scatter.data_source.selected.js_on_change('indices', callback)


# Display the Bokeh plot in Streamlit
st.bokeh_chart(c, use_container_width=True)
```

I have added a div with x and y values, and I am changing text of the div, basis my selection, within callback function. In case you want to plot/show anything with this selection, create that UI in bokeh itself, and pass the complete UI (configured through a layout) to streamlit.